Could not parse argument: project rally API
It used to work until 5/13 - suddenly we are receiving :
Error on request - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcase -
{:errors=>["Could not parse argument: project"], :warnings=>[]}
when trying to update Rally Test Case Verdict.  Can someone guide to what possibly be?
Thanks for the help.
